# gunzip multiple files

Tags: command-line, wildcards, gzip

I have a directory where there are multiple folders, each of folder contains a .gz file.
How can I unzip all of them at once?

My data looks like this

List of folders

```
A
B
C
D
```

In every of them there is file as

```
A
a.out.gz
B
b.out.gz
C
c.out.gz
D
d.out.gz
```

Comment: `gunzip */*.gz` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses `gunzip` to unzip all files in a folder and have the ending `.out.gz`

```
gunzip */*.out.gz
```

This will "loop"* through all folders that have a zipped file in them.  Let me add an example:

```
A
a.out.gz
B
b.out.gz
C
c.out.gz
D
d.out.gz
E
e.out
```

Using the command above, `a.out.gz` `b.out.gz` `c.out.gz` `d.out.gz` will all get unzipped, but it won't touch `e.out` since it isn't zipped.

*this is called *globbing* or *filename expansion*.  You might like to read some more about it [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

Comment: But what if i have multiple folders each of which contains zip file. How can i loop through all folders?

Comment: the `*/*.out.gz` will loop all folders (it's the `*/` part)

Comment: @HoHoHo as mazs point out, this does "loop".  I've added some extra explanation and a link to a page which further explains the concept :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*.gz" -execdir gunzip {} \;
```

the execdir option to find causes 'find' to 'cd' into each directory in turn and run the exec command (gunzip in this case) and then 'cd' back to the cwd